# Python Discod Error 400 by Sandeng an Embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use Python3 and try to send a message with an Embet but it still not working I read the Docs but can not ind out what do I wrong I will post in the following hat the error message was then the code. I you have an idear please post a answer. THX

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KRIShark\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\git\DcBotForBeamMpServerStatus\main.py", line 101, in on_message
    mymessage = await message.channel.send(embed=msg)
  File "C:\Users\KRIShark\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Users\KRIShark\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.6.value: This field is required
In embed.fields.16.value: This field is require
```

---

```
 
def formatmessage(serverdata: server):
  embed = discord.Embed(title=serverName,url=weblink,icon_url=icon,color=discord.Color.blue())
  embed.set_author(name=owner)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
  for attr, value in serverdata.__dict__.items():
        print(attr, value)
        embed.add_field(name=str(attr),value=value,inline=False)
  embed.set_footer(text=weblink)
  return embed
```

and the value is passed into the variable msg

The code what sends the embed:

```
mymessage = await message.channel.send(embed=msg)
```

Comment: make sure that all objects are JSON serializable. try to print the type of the objects

Comment: What's the value of `serverdata.__dict__`? (Also, please, don't iterate over *every possible attribute* like this. Most of discord uses `__slots__` anyway for the speed so this might not even work.)